# AVL Delete method acts strange, C++

Tags: c++, debugging, avl-tree

So I'm implementing an AVL in C++.
As I'm testing the tree functions, a specific test is failing, when I try to do the following:

1. insert 60 to the tree
2. insert 100 to the tree
   ** right now the tree should look like this:

   ```
     100(root)
   60
   ```
3. delete 60 from the tree

** what we expect to happen:

```
    60(root)
```

but instead, I get a seg-fault.
Also, when I try to delete 100, everything is fine!
these are the methods that are being called:

```
void AVL<T, Compare>::Delete(const T& key) {
  Node<T>* node = find(key);
  if (!node) {
    return;
  }
  Node<T>* parent = node->getParent();
  if (node->isLeaf() == 1) {
    leafRemove(node);
    fixBalance(parent);
  } else {
    if ((node->getRight()) && (node->getLeft())) {
      oneChildRemove(node);
    } else {
      twoChildrenRemove(node);
    }
  }
}
```

plus:

```
void AVL<T, Compare>::twoChildrenRemove(Node<T>* node) {
  Node<T>* swapped = getNodeSuccessor(node);
  Node<T>* ancestor = node->getParent();
  swapNodes(node, swapped);
  if (!(swapped->getLeft()) && (!swapped->getRight())) {
    leafRemove(swapped);
  } else {
    oneChildRemove(swapped);
  }
  if (!ancestor) {
    fixBalance(node);
  } else {
    fixBalance(ancestor);
  }
  return;
}
```

and:

```
template<class T, class Compare>
void AVL<T, Compare>::oneChildRemove(Node<T>* node) {
  Node<T>* ancestor = node->getParent(); //=100
  Node<T>* branch;
  if (node->getLeft()) {
    branch = node->getLeft(); 
  }
  if (node->getRight()) {
    branch = node->getRight();
  }
  swapNodes(node, branch);
  leafRemove(branch);
  if (!ancestor) {
    fixBalance(node);
  } else {
    fixBalance(ancestor);
  }
}
```

Can you spot the problem?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand an AVL tree correctly.  If the tree has `60` and `100` in it, and we delete `60`, why should we expect the only remaining element to be `60`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you understand about AVL Tree is wrong.

While deleting a node your algorithm should satisfy the following things,

```
1) If x has no children, delete x.
2) If x has one child, delete x and link x's parent to x's child
3) If x has two children, 
      -find x's successor z [the leftmost node in the rightsubtree of x]
      -replace x's contents with z's contents, and 
      -delete z.
      (Note: z does not have a left child, but may have a right child)
      [since z has at most one child, so we use case (1) or (2) to delete z]
```

I will tell you the concept and you develop from there.

```
void AVL<T, Compare>::oneChildRemove(Node<T>* node) {
      Node<T>* swapped= node->getNodeSuccessor(node); //Get the only child
      Node<T>* ancestor = node->getParent();
      swapNodes(ancestor, swapped); //copy child node(swapped) to point to parent(ancestor)
      leafRemove(node);//Delete the node child
}

void AVL<T, Compare>::twoChildrenRemove(Node<T>* node) {
      Node<T>* ancestor = node->getParent();//Get Parent Node of the node to be deleted.
      Node<T>* rightChild = getRightSuccessor(node);//Get Right Child of the node to be deleted
      Node<T>* leftMostRigthChild = GetLeftMostRightChild(rightChild);//Get Left most child of the right child.
      swapNodes(leftMostRigthChild , ancestor);//copy leftmostrightchild to point to parent

      if (!leftMostRigthChild ->getRight()) { //If no right child for the leftMostRigthChild its leaf node.
           leafRemove(leftMostRigthChild); //So delete it.
      } else {
           oneChildRemove(leftMostRigthChild); //Else it is have one right child and hence call oneChildRemove for the leftMostRigthChild.
      }
      return;
 }
```